# Why is canvas breaking the build after upgrading from nextjs 10.0.5 to 10.0.6?

Tags: webpack, next.js, fabricjs, node-canvas

I upgraded from nextJs from 10.0.5 to 10.0.6 and the build is now failing with the following message:
`Error: Module did not self-register: '.../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node`.

I am not importing canvas directly, but it's used by fabricjs. I am having hard time to understand what's going on here with this `Module did not self-register` error message.

I just figured out that Vercel has been making some changes in the webpack config according to the [release notes](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v10.0.6), so this would be the starting point to investigate, which I did with no success so far.

Side note: the build is still breaking with latest (to date) version 10.0.7 of NextJS. This is unfortunate since it's preventing me to upgrade beyond 10.0.5

### Edit

After some investigation, I identified that the issue is occurring when I am using `getStaticPaths` to generate static files based on dynamic routes. My hypothesis is that nextjs 10.0.6+ is using worker threads in its build process to generate static files based on dynamic routes.

Since worker threads are not supported by canvas (as per [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1394)) this could explain why the build is failing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?